# Fix not drained Using temporary; Using filesort

Tags: mysql

Why such query has issue "Using temporary; Using filesort" on table?

```
Explain 
SELECT `table`.*, COUNT(table.id) AS `count` 
FROM `table` 
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON table.id = table2.foreign_id 
GROUP BY `table2`.`foreign_id` 
ORDER BY table.`title` ASC 

1   SIMPLE  table   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    305     Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  table2  ref     table   table   5   table.id    343     Using index
```

During [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) could be without these slow processes.

EDIT:

Tables are the easiest as could be.

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `foreign_id`(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Does `title` is not unique?

Comment: can you share the definition of table and table2?

Comment: I don't understand what kind of information you want to extract. Generally speaking, displaying all the columns in a table together with a count of IDs will either throw an error or append a column of `1`'s, depending on your settings.

Comment: @Akina yes it is

Comment: @Álvaro González it does not cause error. Query return all records from the table and the number of records from the table2.

Comment: you are joining on int data type with varchar which will not give the expected result.

Comment: you don't have any index so it'll use temp table and sorting explicitly.

Comment: If `title` is defined as unique (and according index exists) then use `GROUP BY table.title`, not by `id`.

Comment: @ROHIT KHURANA sorry it was typing error how i simplified it. In join are both INT and foreign_id is INDEX. ID in table is PRIMARY INDEX.

Comment: @Akina is the same. I don't think it's better to run a group over a varchar data type.

Comment: Oops, I forget that joining is performed by `id`. Create index `(title, id)` and group by title. *I don't think it's better to run a group over a varchar data type.* You perform grouping by the column which is defined as unique - so the column datatype makes no sense.

Comment: You are right. It is count(table2.foreign_id).

Comment: The query looks invalid to me. Have you properly `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` or are you in MySQL's botch mode instead? You group by table2.foreign_id, and table2 is outer joined. That means that you end up with table2.foreign_id NULL for every mismatch, i.e. multiple table.id for this one group. How then can you select table.* when there are multiple table rows for the group? Don't you rather want to have it vice versa, i.e. `GROUP BY table.id` and `COUNT(table2.foreign_id)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
`table`.*  -- This implies that you want all the rows (and all columns)
COUNT(table.id)  -- This implies that you just one a single number
```

Although MySQL let you run the query, it is not a proper query.  (And, in version 8.0, it will spit at you.)

If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, then `GROUP BY table.id` further complicates the issue.  That says to produce one row for each `id`.  But since `id` is unique, there is only one row for each id.  So the `GROUP BY` is redundant.

Please describe what the query is supposed to do; we can help you correctly formulate it.

Meanwhile, use InnoDB instead of MyISAM.

Comment: You are right. It is count(table2.foreign_id). It is simple query which return all records from table and count of records with id from table in table2.